# argparse unrecognized arguments

Tags: python, argparse, pytorch

i'am running pytorch DBPN(super resolution model) which the author of the paper  uploaded. But, i'm in trouble to training these model. Maybe, a problem is came from argparse. But i can't recognize how to fix it.. please help me, Thanks.

DBPN code link : https://github.com/alterzero/DBPN-Pytorch

```
`Testing started at 2:14 am..
C:\Users\CY\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.2.4\helpers\pycharm\_jb_pytest_runner.py" --path C:/Users/CY/Desktop/SuperResol/DBPN-Pytorch-master/main.py
Launching pytest with arguments C:/Users/CY/Desktop/SuperResol/DBPN-Pytorch-master/main.py in C:\Users\CY\Desktop\SuperResol\DBPN-Pytorch-master

============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.5.6, pytest-3.8.1, py-1.6.0, pluggy-0.7.1
rootdir: C:\Users\CY\Desktop\SuperResol\DBPN-Pytorch-master, inifile:usage: _jb_pytest_runner.py [-h] [--upscale_factor UPSCALE_FACTOR]
                            [--batchSize BATCHSIZE]
                            [--testBatchSize TESTBATCHSIZE]
                            [--nEpochs NEPOCHS] [--snapshots SNAPSHOTS]
                            [--lr LR] [--gpu_mode GPU_MODE]
                            [--threads THREADS] [--seed SEED] [--gpus GPUS]
                            [--data_dir DATA_DIR]
                            [--data_augmentation DATA_AUGMENTATION]
                            [--hr_train_dataset HR_TRAIN_DATASET]
                            [--train_dataset TRAIN_DATASET]
                            [--hr_test_dataset HR_TEST_DATASET]
                            [--test_dataset TEST_DATASET]
                            [--model_type MODEL_TYPE]
                            [--patch_size PATCH_SIZE]
                            [--pretrained_sr PRETRAINED_SR]
                            [--pretrained PRETRAINED]
                            [--save_folder SAVE_FOLDER] [--prefix PREFIX]
_jb_pytest_runner.py: error: unrecognized arguments: C:/Users/CY/Desktop/SuperResol/DBPN-Pytorch-master/main.py

main.py:None (main.py)
main.py:44: in <module>
    opt = parser.parse_args()
..\..\..\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\argparse.py:1729: in parse_args
    self.error(msg % ' '.join(argv))
..\..\..\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\argparse.py:2385: in error
    self.exit(2, _('%(prog)s: error: %(message)s\n') % args)
..\..\..\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\argparse.py:2372: in exit
    _sys.exit(status)
E   SystemExit: 2
collected 0 items / 1 errors

=================================== ERRORS ====================================
__________________________ ERROR collecting main.py ___________________________
main.py:44: in <module>
    opt = parser.parse_args()
..\..\..\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\argparse.py:1729: in parse_args
    self.error(msg % ' '.join(argv))
..\..\..\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\argparse.py:2385: in error
    self.exit(2, _('%(prog)s: error: %(message)s\n') % args)
..\..\..\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\argparse.py:2372: in exit
    _sys.exit(status)
E   SystemExit: 2
------------------------------- Captured stderr -------------------------------
usage: _jb_pytest_runner.py [-h] [--upscale_factor UPSCALE_FACTOR]
                            [--batchSize BATCHSIZE]
                            [--testBatchSize TESTBATCHSIZE]
                            [--nEpochs NEPOCHS] [--snapshots SNAPSHOTS]
                            [--lr LR] [--gpu_mode GPU_MODE]
                            [--threads THREADS] [--seed SEED] [--gpus GPUS]
                            [--data_dir DATA_DIR]
                            [--data_augmentation DATA_AUGMENTATION]
                            [--hr_train_dataset HR_TRAIN_DATASET]
                            [--train_dataset TRAIN_DATASET]
                            [--hr_test_dataset HR_TEST_DATASET]
                            [--test_dataset TEST_DATASET]
                            [--model_type MODEL_TYPE]
                            [--patch_size PATCH_SIZE]
                            [--pretrained_sr PRETRAINED_SR]
                            [--pretrained PRETRAINED]
                            [--save_folder SAVE_FOLDER] [--prefix PREFIX]
_jb_pytest_runner.py: error: unrecognized arguments: C:/Users/CY/Desktop/SuperResol/DBPN-Pytorch-master/main.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=========================== 1 error in 0.52 seconds ===========================
Process finished with exit code 0
`
```

Comment: My guess is there's a conflict between the commandline arguments that `pytest` can use, and ones that your `PYtorch` script can use.

Comment: My pytest version is 3.8.1 and pytorch version is 0.3.1!